# Selenium Data Driven Testing with C#

Tags: selenium, testing, data-driven-tests

I want to perform data driven testing in selenium using ASP.NET(C#),ajax and almost all the features of jquery. Can anyone  give me the step how to perform data driven testing using C#
or some demo through which I can perform my testing?

Comment: have you tried: http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=selenium++tutorial&meta=

Answer (score 1):

Step1: First download selenium web driver from this link- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Step2: then download NUnit jar files.

Step3:The follow this link- http://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/07/31/getting-started-using-selenium-2-0-webdriver-for-ie-in-visual-studio-c/

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean when you want to do AJAX with Selenium and jQuery. Your site should be doing the AJAX and selenium should be firing off the requests.

If you want to do C# and NUnit tests, which is the standard way to write c# tests, then my site has a [tutorial](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/seleniumtraining/selenium_csharp_nunit.htm) to get you going. All you need to do is to write code to access your datastore and then a loop round that data when doing your test